# onClose and datepick with jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code:

```
$('#popupDatepickerWeekly').datepick({
   maxDate:'1Y',
   mandatory:true,
   highlightWeek:true,
   onClose: closedDate
});
```

My closedDate function looks like this:

```
function closedDate(value, date, inst) { 
 document.signUpForm.repeatUntil.value = value;
}
```

But when I pick a date using the datepicker, the repeatUntil hidden value is not set.

The hidden form field looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="repeatUntil" value="">
```

I don't get an error or anything, but it always comes back as an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your closedDate function to this:

```
function closedDate(value, date, inst) { 
 $("input[name=repeatUntil]").val(value);
}
```

Or use an anonymous function like this:

```
$('#popupDatepickerWeekly').datepick({
   maxDate:'1Y',
   mandatory:true,
   highlightWeek:true,
   onClose: function(value) { 
     $("input[name=repeatUntil]").val(value);
   }
});
```